# ReadAllBytes from bitmap in memory instead of from file

Tags: .net, vb.net, bitmap

I can get the bytes of an image file like this:

```
    Dim nBytes() As Byte
    nBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(uPath)
```

This works fine, however I would like to get the bytes from a bitmap which only exists in memory.

I would not like to save it to a file first.

Is that possible, and if yes, how?

Thank you.

Comment: Save it to a MemoryStream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming Bitmap is `System.Drawing.Bitmap`

```
Using ms As New MemoryStream()
    myBitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.xxx)
    ms.Position = 0

    Return ms.ToArray()
End Using
```

The `ms.Position = 0` line might not be needed with just calling `ToArray()`. I was setting the memory stream to another object's stream property it needed to be reset in that situation.

Comment: @tmighty No problem. I just happened to be currently in one of my projects where I needed to do it.